# Can't play iOS video on Android

Tags: android, ios, video, h.264, mpeg

Can't play video recorded(using different configurations) on iOS camera. The below is the video info of recorded video :

```
General
CompleteName                     : C:\Users\theuset\Videos\VideoA1.mp4
Format                           : MPEG-4
Format_Profile                   : QuickTime
CodecID                          : qt  
FileSize/String                  : 362 KiB
Duration/String                  : 12s 840ms
OverallBitRate/String            : 231 Kbps
Encoded_Date                     : UTC 2015-09-09 20:27:10
Tagged_Date                      : UTC 2015-09-09 20:28:04
Encoded_Library/String           : Apple QuickTime

Video
ID/String                        : 1
Format                           : AVC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
Format_Profile                   : Baseline@L3
Format_Settings_CABAC/String     : No
Format_Settings_RefFrames/String : 1 frame
Format_Settings_GOP              : M=1, N=16
CodecID                          : avc1
CodecID/Info                     : Advanced Video Coding
Duration/String                  : 12s 840ms
BitRate/String                   : 229 Kbps
Width/String                     : 360 pixels
Width_CleanAperture/String       : 360 pixels
Height/String                    : 360 pixels
Height_CleanAperture/String      : 360 pixels
DisplayAspectRatio/String        : 1.000
DisplayAspectRatio_CleanAperture : 1.000
FrameRate_Mode/String            : Variable
FrameRate/String                 : 29.439 fps
FrameRate_Minimum/String         : 4.286 fps
FrameRate_Maximum/String         : 30.000 fps
ColorSpace                       : YUV
ChromaSubsampling                : 4:2:0
BitDepth/String                  : 8 bits
ScanType/String                  : Progressive
Bits-(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.060
StreamSize/String                : 359 KiB (99%)
Title                            : Core Media Video
Encoded_Date                     : UTC 2015-09-09 20:27:10
Tagged_Date                      : UTC 2015-09-09 20:28:04
```

I've checked it with standard Android player on Nexus 7(KitKat),it says "Can't play video", on devices with Andoird 5.1 it works.
Could someone please tell what exactly prevents playing this video on Android, because as far as I know `H.264 BaseLine L3` is supported by Android.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's because:

> Encoded_Library/String           : Apple QuickTime

Android doesn't support Apple Quicktime.